# shared_ptr and slicing

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Someone I worked with once said that shared_ptr was unsafe and would slice when casting from a derived class to a base class (i.e. upcasting). For example if there were 2 classes A and B where B derived from A, then

```
shared_ptr<A> a(new B)
```

would slice. I pointed him to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm
where it says

> `shared_ptr<T>` can be implicitly converted to `shared_ptr<U>` whenever `T*` can be implicitly converted to `U*`.

implied that it's safe to use in those contexts but he didn't seem to think so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That someone is wrong, [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) doesn't apply to pointers. That the pointer usage is wrapped away in a `shared_ptr` doesn't change that - it doesn't do any particular magic here, it initializes an internal pointer with the value passed to its constructor.

Simplified it could look e.g. like this for the purpose of this question:

```
template<class T> struct ptr {
    T* t;
    ptr(T* t) : t(t) {}
    // ...
};
```

You lose the static type-information of `B`, yes, but nothing changes regarding the object pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

### It is true that object slicing doesn't apply to pointers

Pointers are PODs (just for the record: `shared_ptr`s aren't).

The question quotes:

> shared_ptr can be implicitly converted to shared_ptr whenever T* can be implicitly converted to U*.

This is about converting from one type to another, which is different from upcasting. There's no inheritance relationship between `shared_ptr<A>` and `shared_ptr<B>`, whether or not `A` derives from `B` or viceversa. This is the reason why the `shared_ptr` object itself doesn't slice.

### It is not true that object slicing cannot be a concern

Consider a class hierarchy A, B with no virtual destructors.

```
std::shared_ptr<A> a(new B);
auto a = std::make_shared<B>();
```

will capture B's deallocator and then will call B's destructor when needed

```
std::shared_ptr<A> a((A*)(new B));
```

will do no such thing and will cause slicing problems in the pointed-to object.

### It is not true that nothing is changed by the fact that the pointer usage is wrapped away in a smart pointer

For example, using `unique_ptr` has different behaviour:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> a(new B);
std::unique_ptr<A> a((A*)(new B));
```

will both exhibit slicing problems, while

```
auto a = std::make_unique<B>();
```

won't.

Using a plain pointer doesn't help either:

```
A* a = new B{};
delete a;
```

is a recipe for disaster.

Example code available [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c12698b3b58c792).

Comment: You begin by stating that raw pointers cannot slice, and end with an exemple of slicing with raw pointers... Have I missed something ?

Comment: It's not the pointer that slices, it's the object pointed to that experiences slicing problems. Hope this solve your doubt; if it doesn't I'll try to come up with an example or something, but I can't think of anything at the moment. I didn't find a better way to express that but if you find any better wording for any part of the answer, do suggest it please.