# What are the arguments against using size_t?

Tags: c++, types, c99

I have a API like this,

```
class IoType {
......
    StatusType writeBytes(......, size_t& bytesWritten);
    StatusType writeObjects(......, size_t& objsWritten);
};
```

A senior member of the team who I respect seems to have a problem with the type size_t and suggest that I use C99 types. I know it sounds stupid but I always think c99 types like uint32_t and uint64_t look ugly. I do use them but only when it's really necessary, for instance when I need to serialize/deserialize a structure, I do want to be specific about the sizes of my data members.

What are the arguments against using size_t? I know it's not a real type but if I know for sure even a 32-bit integer is enough for me and a size type seems to be appropriate for number of bytes or number of objects, etc.

Comment: The "senior member of the team" is an idiot.

Comment: Did you ask the reason ?

Comment: @iammilind, not yet. I was pondering if it's worth bringing up.

Comment: I've had had senior members tell me that shared_ptrs slice (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305753/shared-ptr-and-slicing) That was really frustrating coupled with the fact that he had an alpha geek attitude augmented with a non-argument for why the boost docs were wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use exact-size types like `uint32_t` whenever you're dealing with serialization of any sort (binary files, networking, etc.).  Use `size_t` whenever you're dealing with the size of an object in memory—that's what it's intended for.  All of the functions that deal with object sizes, like `malloc`, `strlen`, and the `sizeof` operator all `size_t`.

If you use `size_t` correctly, your program will be maximally portable, and it will not waste time and memory on platforms where it doesn't need to.  On 32-bit platforms, a `size_t` will be 32 bits—if you instead used a `uint64_t`, you'd waste time and space.  Conversely, on 64-bit platforms, a `size_t` will be 64 bits—if you instead used a `uint32_t`, your program could behave incorrectly (maybe even crash or open up a security vulnerability) if it ever had to deal with a piece of memory larger than 4 GB.

Comment: I agree with you. The problem is that besides using size_t for memory size or array size or string size, etc. I'm using it for number of bytes or number of objects, not entirely its intended use. Is that a good practice? Or at least is that acceptable?

Comment: @grokus: Number of bytes is a perfectly good use for `size_t`.  For number of objects, it could go either way: you could use `size_t`, or you could use a plain old `int` if you don't think there's any way you'd have over 4 billion objects.

Comment: @Adam: regarding "4 billion": an `int` formally only guarantees the 16-bit range -32767 through +32767. The apparently missing bottom value is because two's complement representation is not guaranteed either.

Comment: @Alf: Yes, that's true.  If you want to be portable to systems with 16-bit `int`s, then you need to be more careful, but the fraction of software that gets written these days that needs to be 16-bit compatible is miniscule.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, it's not a good idea to replace `size_t` (a maximally portable thing) with a less portable C99 fixed size or minimum size unsigned type.

On the other hand, you can avoid a lot of technical problems (wasted time) by using the signed `ptrdiff_t` type instead. The standard library’s use of unsigned type is just for historical reasons. It made sense in its day, and even today on 16-bit architectures, but generally it is nothing but trouble & verbosity.

Making that change requires some support, though, in particular **[a general `size` function](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/how-to-avoid-disastrous-integer-wrap-around/#wrappers)** that returns array or container size as `ptrdiff_t`.

---

Now, regarding your function signature

```
    StatusType writeBytes(......, size_t& bytesWritten);
```

This *forces* the calling code’s choice of type for the bytes written count.

And then, with unsigned type `size_t` forced, it is easy to introduce a bug, e.g. by checking if that is less or more than some computed quantity.

A grotesque example: `std::string("ah").length() < -5` is guaranteed `true`.

So instead, make that …

```
    Size writeBytes(......);
```

or, if you do not want to use exceptions,

```
    Size writeBytes(......, StatusType& status );
```

It is OK to have an enumeration of possible statuses as unsigned type or as whatever, because the only operations on status values will be equality checking and possibly as keys.

Comment: What if you have a 3-gigabyte object on a 32-bit system?

Comment: @Keith: then you must do as you must do, treat it very specially. :-) Or better, just don't do that. It is likely to cause some severe trashing in Windows (when you have increased available address space from 2G), and I suspect the same is the case for *nix.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything wrong in using `size_t` in contexts where you don't need to serialize values. Also using `size_t` correctly will increase the code's safety/portability across 32 and 64 bit patforms.

Comment: One thing I should add is that we are a startup and are doing development on a 64-bit platform off the bat, so there is no 32 to 64 bit problem.

Comment: Why look backwards?  size_t will also "just work" on tomorrow's 128-bit systems.  This is not even a close call.  Like I said, your "senior" team member is an idiot.