# Transform type of polymorphic object without smart pointer expirence

Tags: c++, polymorphism, smart-pointers

```
class Animal
{
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
};

class Elephant : public Animal
{
};
```

There is collection of animal objects:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Animal>> animals;
```

Somewhere in the program there are also other shared pointers and weak pointers referring to the objects in "animals" collection.

For example at index 0 of animals there is `Dog` object.

```
std::shared_ptr<Dog>& dog = std::static_pointer_cast<Dog>(animals[0]);
```

I need to transform type of this object to `Elephant`. I can't just delete this object(`Dog`), and create new(`Elephant`), because weak pointers will expire, and other shared pointers will refer to old object, not new.
I need to do this in way, that weak pointers and other shared pointers will still refer to same object - but type will be different(transformed).
All references are of `Animal` type, so there wont be situations where reference to `Dog` exists however it's `Elephant` already.

How do I do it? Is such practice considered hack?

Edit(Some more information):

Problem I have exists in game. For game needings, I need sometimes to transform animal to monster, monster to NPC.
Problem is that there are many references to different actors. For example some monster can have selected target of another monster(so monster owns weak pointer to another monster). The class hierarchy I gave is just example, but for the real it looks Like this. Actor -> Monster, Animal, NPC, Player

Comment: You wish to transform a dog into an elephant? I would advise against this course of action.

Comment: Why? `Elephant` is not `Dog` and vice versa,

Comment: @user4581301: That sort of small, timid thinking exactly makes the difference between why Darwin got a nobel prize and why you don't even get a user name. Think big, dare to be different. :-)

Comment: It's on the needings of a game. There are situations where I need to transform monster to animal, etc.

Comment: The class hierarchy is clear, but not the usage that produces your problems. Add a few words more about it, maybe with some example code.

Comment: You can't just change an object's type in C++. You have to destruct it and construct another, and I see no well-defined way of doing that without updating every pointer to the previous object.

Comment: If you have (say) a shape-changing animal, then you could make a new type for that and it can contain its own pointer to whichever animal it is currently representing.

Comment: Most important thing is the **virtual destructor in the base class**.

Comment: So if you want to transform an *animal* to a *monster* are you saying that *animals* can't be *monsters*? And *monsters* can't be *NPCs*?

Comment: @Galik Well, it potentially could, its good idea to make animal / monster / npc one thing. However there are also situations where monster can be transformed to player or player to monster, and it completly does not match. I didn't predict that I will need such transformations when designing it.

Comment: I could be way off here but I thought maybe that a creature could be either a player or a NPC or a monster. What I mean is the *role* of the creature would be separate from its form/type. Otherwise how are you going to have different types of NPCs? Or different types of monsters? I mean if a *giraffe* becomes one *NPC* and a *tiger* becomes another *NPC* isn't the fact that you have a *giraffe* and a *tiger* separate from their happening to also be `NPCs`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Surprisingly, Darwin and I are even on the Nobel Prize front. Despite being one of the most deserving scientists in history, he  never received a Nobel Prize for the simple reason that the prize cannot be won, but can be awarded, posthumously, and Darwin died before the prize was founded.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with another level of indirection: instead of using `Animal` directly you might create something like this:

```
class ShiftingAnimal
{
    ShiftingAnimal(std::unique_ptr<Animal> animal){...}
    void shift(std::unique_ptr<Animal> newAnimal){...}
}
```

and use `std::shared_ptr<ShiftingAnimal>` throughout your program.

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional layer of indirection. Create a wrapper that owns the animal pointer:

```
struct animal_wrapper {
    std::unique_ptr<Animal> handle;
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<animal_wrapper>> animals;
```

Now you can change the object that `Wrapper::animal` points to, and all the shared pointers pointing to that wrapper will remain valid.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say:

> Somewhere in the program there are also other shared pointers and weak pointers referring to the objects in "animals" collection.

but it appears that you don't want a pointer to the objects, you want something that refers to a location that might contains different objects at different times.

### Possible solutions

1. "somewhere in the program" you can use iterators rather than shared/weak pointers to the object; this way, when you change the content of a particular location in the vector, you keep having the reference to the correct object. The viability of this depends on your use of the vector: you can only do this if you know that the usage pattern never invalidates iterators (which is very unlikely).
2. same as before, but instead of iterators store indexes. This is slightly less unlikely to be viable (you can now afford reallocations as long as you never insert in the middle/change the ordering/remove elements)
3. add a level of indirection, as suggested in other answers.

### Adding a level of indirection

This was suggested in other answers and is the most generic way of achieving your goal; I see no reason for writing a new class/struct though. I'd suggest using `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<Animal>>>`, i.e. a vector of shared pointers that refer to a location that might contain different objects at different times (or no object for that matter). Notice that the additional level of indirection adds some "weirdness" to the usage pattern in both cases (plain unique_ptr and wrapper class). [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8150c51395a86614) you can find code showing both options.

Also notice that if you start using unique_ptr rather than just shared_ptr, you might need to have a virtual destructor for the Animal class (see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305753/shared-ptr-and-slicing/37344373#37344373)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: concerning indexes, I couldn't do it, because animal can die, and it is deleted from collection